# Receiving PHP Warning: Module '[module name]' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo, server

I'm Trying to learn Laravel and PHP while learning how to manage a server. I was trying to fix a different problem, something about a PDO driver not being found when trying to read from a sqlite database.

My server is running PHP 7.0, I actually upgraded it from 5.5.9 using this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

In an attempt to fix the PDO driver problem, I run the following command:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

This doesn't fix the problem, but now every time I run a PHP command, I am met with the following line of text:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'shmop' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'zlib' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I have found many articles online about this issue, they all say I just have to uncomment lines in my php.ini file. Running phpinfo() shows that my loaded configuration file is here:

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

I go to that file, and I do a search for "extension=" but I see that every mention of extension is already commented out. See example:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
```

I see in phpinfo() two more things that could be related to something. "Scan this dir for additional .ini files shows"

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d
```

"And my additional .ini files parsed" shows:

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-zlib.ini
```

I don't want to mess up my server anymore, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to fix these errors. I have since uninstalled php5-mysql, didn't fix the problem as expected. As a bonus, if anyone knows how to correctly fix the following PDO error after attempting to read a sqlite database, that would be amazing:

```
[PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post content of `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini`

Comment: The contents are:

`; configuration for php common module
; priority=10
extension=pdo.so`

Comment: Are they in same line? ; is comment. If they in same line then extension=pdo.so is not loaded. If they are not in same line, this is where pdo.so is loaded.

Comment: Yes, they are on different lines, this comment section doesn't like line breaks. What does this mean for the issue I'm having?

Comment: This line `;extension=php_bz2.dll` is PHP.ini for Windows server. in Linux I believe is must be .SO file not .DLL. You said "PDO error after attempting to read a sqlite database". I thought you try to use MySQL not SQLite? If you try to use SQLite then you must also install PHP extension for SQLite.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry if my initial statement is misleading. That is only a preface for my real issue with the PHP module warnings.

Comment: Check my answer here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/764033/php-7-module-already-loaded-warnings/764512#764512 more characters

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because you try to install `php5-mysql` on top of PHP7. As the name said it is PHP5 extension. The other extension comes with PHP7 may already be loaded. Because you use PHP7, then make sure you load correct PHP7 extension. Try to install PHP7.0-mysql extension and then restart web server.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I realized after the fact, and I'll admit I did it without thinking. Do you have a proposed solution to fixing the warnings that I'm receiving? Where would this module install itself in an ubuntu system and what files would it leave behind after being uninstalled?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and only have php7.0 modules installed so I don't think this would be the cause.